# How does multikicker work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I don't understand [Strength of the Tajuru](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Strength%20of%20the%20Tajuru). What does multikicker mean, and how would I use it in a game?

Comment: I'm sure someone will write you an excellent answer before long, but in the meantime, you might try reading the rulings on [the card's Gatherer entry](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=strength+of+the+tajuru). There's a concrete example in there.

Answer (score 2):

First, in order to understand how Multikicker works you have to understand how Kicker works. What Kicker {cost} means is that when you cast the spell (before you do anything like choose targets or determine cost) you decide if you are going to 'kick' the spell, if you do you pay {cost} in addition to any other costs of the spell, and it will have a different effect if it was kicked. For example [Ardent Soldier](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ardent%20Soldier) has `Kicker {2}` and `If Ardent Soldier was kicked, it enters the battlefield with a +1/+1 counter on it.` So when you cast the Soldier if you pay an additional {2} it will enter the battlefield with a +1/+1 counter. Normally you can only kick a spell once, but what Multikicker allows you to do is kick the spell as many times as you can pay for.

Strength of the Tajuru can be a little confusing since it has an {X} in its cost in addition to the Multikicker. How it will work is you decide how many counters you want to place on each creature, this value will be the {X} in the cost, then you decide how many creatures you want to target, the first one is free every additional one cost {1} from the Multikicker. So your final cost would come out to {X}{# of targets - 1}{G}{G}.

From the [Gatherer Rulings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=strength%20of%20the%20tajuru):

> For example, if you want to put four +1/+1 counters on each of three different targets, that means X is 4 and you're kicking the spell twice. You'll pay a mana cost of {4}{G}{G}, plus a kicker cost of {1}, plus another kicker cost of {1}, for a total of {6}{G}{G}.

Strength of the Tajuru is probably the most complicated of the multikicker cards, most of them are much simpler, take for example [Apex Hawks](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Apex%20Hawks). The Hawks have `Multikicker {1}{W}` and `Apex Hawks enters the battlefield with a +1/+1 counter on it for each time it was kicked.`, what this means is as you cast the Hawks you can pay {1}{W} as many times as you want in addition to the regular cost of the spell, and for every time you do that it gets a +1/+1 counter. So if you payed {3}{W}{W}{W} for the Multikicker it would enter the battlefield with 3 +1/+1 counters.

Comment: It might also help to look at a simpler example, without the {X} and where the cost isn't just {1} - say [Apex Hawks](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382214). Pay {1}{W} once, get one +1/+1 counter. Pay it twice, get two.

Answer (score 0):

In case you were confused, the X in Strength of the Tajuru's cost is unrelated to multikicker. If you need help understanding that mechanic, see [What does X mean in a spell's cost?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/21056/6692). Now, to understand Multikicker, it helps to understand Kicker first.

**Kicker**

Kicker is an extra cost that you may pay when you cast the spell. If you choose to pay the cost, then the spell has been "kicked". Generally, you will get some additional effect if the card was kicked. If you don't pay the cost, then you don't get the extra effect.

[image]

- If you cast MySpell for [image], then it deals 1 damage to target creature or planeswalker.
- If you cast MySpell for [image][image], then MySpell deals 1 damage to target creature or planeswalker and you gain 4 life.

**Multikicker**

Multikicker is a variant of kicker. If you pay the multikicker cost, then the spell has been "kicked". If you pay the multikicker cost N times, then the spell has been kicked N times.

[image]

- If you cast AnotherSpell for [image], creatures you control get +0/+1 until the end of turn.
- If you cast AnotherSpell for [image][image], creatures you control get +0/+1 until the end of turn and all creatures get -1/-1 until the end of turn.
- If you cast AnotherSpell for [image][image][image][image][image][image][image], creatures you control get +0/+1 until the end of turn and all creatures get -6/-6 until the end of turn.

Comment: Did you mean {W}{R} on your first example? Also I think an easy source of confusion for Strength of the Tajuru is the {X} vs the {1} per kick (i.e. two different things that are both increments of {1}) - might be worth addressing the card in the question too.

Comment: @Jefromi If OP is actually confused about the X in a spell's cost, then he needs to ask a new question anyway.

Comment: Is it be possible to maneuver the bullet points to the right of the picture? It would literally cut the answer's length in half. I don't think we have that kind of control, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that's not currently possible. [Related meta.SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99573/can-we-get-a-way-to-wrap-text-around-images)

Comment: The question did ask about a specific example. It was originally in the title, so in case you thought that because it was now only in the body it wasn't actually a required part of the question, I've put it back in the title too.

Comment: @Jefromi I understand that you are just trying to be proactive, but in this case I think you are being a little too aggressive about trying to read the OP's mind. He hasn't demonstrated any confusion about X in the spell's cost. I don't intend to address confusion that I can't see.

Comment: @Jefromi After watching you make the title of the question worse, I caved and decided to add a sentence or two addressing that aspect of the card. Does that satisfy your concern?

Comment: @Rainbolt I don't know exactly what the source of the OP's confusion is, but he asked about a specific card. Arguably I went too far by *removing* it from the title, especially since it caused you to think that an answer which didn't address it still answered the question, so I don't think putting it back in made it worse.

Comment: Also to be clear, I said that the {X} was an easy source of confusion - I did not say that it was the only reason the OP asked about that card. Even if it *didn't* say {X} on the card, the OP asking about a specific card is certainly reason enough to discuss that card in your answer.

Comment: @Jefromi Did you just comment to tell me that you have no idea what the OP is asking, and that *your* best guess should align with *my* best guess?

Comment: @Rainbolt No, I said that no matter what, you should address the actual card the OP asked about, and clarified that I was *not* saying that you had to think {X} vs multikicker {1} was confusing, just that it was one seemingly-likely thing the OP *could have* found confusing in an attempt to be helpful.

Comment: @Jefromi I disagree that I have to, or even *should*, use the same example card that the OP used. Sometimes mechanics are far better explained using much simpler examples. **If the OP was confused by a *different* mechanic, then he needs to ask a *different* question**, even if that mechanic happens to be on the same card.

Comment: @Jefromi Your last few comments really overstep the bounds of what the comments section is for. You haven't made a real suggestion for improving this answer other than "It should address this card." What specifically about the card needs addressing? After all, if you simply asked "How does this card work?" then I would have to cover half of the entire rulebook. You need to leave more specific comments.